# Hover on the whole front card and not just on the buttons

Tags: css

How do you make the card to transform when hovering on the whole front card and not just on the button ,I tried to add the the ID and class on the front div but the card just auto transforms. https://jsfiddle.net/ecbumaw9/

```
.more {
display: none;
}
.more:checked ~ .content {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Put the hover on your .card class.

Comment: It's unclear to me what specific effect you are referring to. Do you mean the change in color when hovering over the button, or the rotation transition of the card when clicking the button? Please create a smaller example that only shows the effect you have a question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:hover` to the `.card` class and reference the child. It should work.

Modify your CSS as follows:

```
.more:checked ~ .content, .card:hover  .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 1em;
  /*perspective: 1500px;*/
}

.card .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.85, 1);
}

.more {
  display: none;
}

.more:checked~.content,
.card:hover .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.front .inner,
.back .inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  padding: 1.3em;
  transform: translateZ(80px) scale(0.94);
}

.back .inner {
  padding: 1em !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.front {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.front:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(67, 138, 243, 0.7), rgba(255, 242, 166, 0.7));
}

.front .inner {
  grid-template-rows: 5fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

.front h2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #151515;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

.front .rating {
  grid-row: 3;
  color: #ffe234;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.front .rating i {
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #a1e8b9;
}

.back .inner {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 14fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-column-gap: 0.8em;
  justify-items: inherit;
}

.back .info {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #696969;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.back .info:not(:first-of-type):before {
  /*content: '';*/
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.9em;
  height: 18px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.back .info span {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.back .info i {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.back .info i:before {
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #355cc9, #438af3);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.back .info .icon {
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

.back .info .icon span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -0.25em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.back .description {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  font-size: 0.70em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #000;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.back .description ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.back .description li {
  padding: 6px;
}

.back .description span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.back .description p {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.draw-border {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #a1e8b9;
  transition: color 0.25s 0.0833333333s;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.draw-border::before,
.draw-border::after {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.draw-border::before {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
}

.draw-border::after {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
}

.draw-border:hover {
  color: #696969;
}

.draw-border:hover::before,
.draw-border:hover::after {
  border-color: #696969;
  transition: border-color 0s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.draw-border:hover::before {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.25s;
}

.draw-border:hover::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.25s, 0s;
}

.btn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  margin: 5px;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 2px dotted #55d7dc;
}

.back .location,
.back .price {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #696969;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 0.86em;
}

.back .location {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  justify-self: left;
}

.back .price {
  grid-column: 3/-1;
  justify-self: right;
}

.back .button {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  justify-self: center;
}

.button {
  grid-row: -1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 2.9em;
  min-width: 3em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.button.return {
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #696969;
  border-color: #696969;
  text-shadow: none;
  height: 2em !important;
}

.button.return:hover {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #707070;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #355cc9;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #a1e8b9;
  }
  .card {
    width: 820px !important;
    height: 440px !important;
    margin: 1em !important;
  }
  .back .description {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .back .description li {
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 16px;
  }
  .back .info span {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .back .location,
  .back .price {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }
  .draw-border {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .draw-border:hover {
    color: #696969;
  }
  /* Styles */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <input type="checkbox" id="card1" class="more" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="front" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Chicago_Skyline_%2815240030464%29.jpg/800px-Chicago_Skyline_%2815240030464%29.jpg')">
        <div class="inner">
          <h2>Chicago Events For A Year Ahead</h2>
          <div class="rating">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          </div>
          <label for="card1" class="button" aria-hidden="true">
                           Check Events
                        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="info">
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> -->
            <span>Month</span>
            <div class="icon">


            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span>Event Type</span>
            <div class="icon">
              <!-- <i class="fa fa-door-open"></i> -->

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <!--  <span>Event</span> -->
            <div class="icon">
              <!--  <i class="fa fa-bed"></i>
                                 -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="description">
            <ul>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Sep</span> Fall Whiskey </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Oct</span> Halloween Bar Crawl Fri & Sat </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Dec</span> NYE Bar Crawl </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Dec</span> NYE Yacht </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Jan</span> Winter Whiskey </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Feb</span> Winter Tequila </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Mar</span> St Patrick's Bar Crawl </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Jun</span> Summer Whiskey </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Jul</span> Summer Tequila </li>
              <li class="btn draw-border"> <span>Aug</span> Air Show Yacht Party </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <div class="location">Chicago Events </div>
          <div class="price">2019-2020</div>
          <label for="card1" class="button return" aria-hidden="true">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rfbac5zt/)

Comment: This has some unexpected and possibly UX unfriendly behavior when clicking the buttons.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The OP must probably remove the button for a more user friendly approach or remove the 'hover to rotate' effect.

Comment: Is it not recommended to use the hover on the whole card?, should I retain it as clickable button?

Comment: It's your call. The user sees a button first and  he moves his mouse pointer to click it. But we have given hover effect for rotating the card too which the user doesn't know and he won't be able to click the button. As soon as he hovers the card, it rotates and gives no room for the user to click the button.